# C++ - How to typdef templated struct pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

Here is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct Doublenode{
    T data;
    struct Doublenode<T>* prev;
    struct Doublenode<T>* next;
};
template<typename T>
using Double_node = typename Doublenode <T>::Double_node;
template<typename T>
using DoubleNodePtr = typename Double_node <T>* ::DoubleNodePtr;
```

This gives me the folowing error:

> error: expected nested-name-specifier
>    using DoubleNodePtr = typename (^)Double_node * ::DoubleNodePtr;

What is the right way to typdef a templated struct pointer?

Comment: Just a personal preference, but *I* would prefer `using` over `typedef`. It reads more easily.

Comment: That `^` suggests this is not C++, but C++/CLI, even though I can find no evidence of that in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of a `using` type alias, be it templated or not, is as follows:

```
using <alias name> = <existing type name>;
```

You are writing it as

```
using <alias name> = <existing type name> :: <alias name>;
```

It *could work* if `<existing type name>` has a member type named like `<alias name>`. But it's not correct in general. You problem, ultimately, seems to be about misunderstanding the required syntax. Which when applied to your post is simply:

```
template<typename T>
using Double_node = Doublenode<T>;
```

Comment: Yeah was going to say. Anything other than what you've written here is a distraction from the core misunderstanding. OP probably saw `using` used as a "scope-remover" somewhere and misunderstood it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> template<typename T>
> using DoubleNodePtr = typename Double_node <T>* ::DoubleNodePtr;
> ```

Pointer types do not have members or a scope, so you cannot apply the scope resolution operator on a pointer.

> ```
> template<typename T>
> using Double_node = typename Doublenode <T>::Double_node;
> ```

`Doublenode` doesn't have a member called `Double_node`, so this can only be sensible if you intend to specialize `Doublenode` and those specializations have that member.

---

> C++ - How to typdef templated struct pointer?

Like this:

```
template<typename T>
using DoubleNodePtr = Double_node<T>*;
```

However, it is usually a bad idea to create a type alias for a pointer. Don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
using Double_node = Doublenode<T>;

template<typename T>
using DoubleNodePtr = Double_node<T>*;
```